# What is the meaning of 過ぎる in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, verbs

The verb 過ぎる shows up in the following sentence:

> 二年間の景気後退期を**過ぎれ**ば、この国の経済は最悪の状態を脱するかもしれません。

I think I understand the sentence but the problem is that I'm not sure what 過ぎる exactly means. It is in its ば conditional form, right? What would be the meaning of 過ぎる in this sentence? 
助けてください

Comment: @DXV, Please write answers in the answer section. [Comments are not for answers.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/9831)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「二年間{にねんかん}の景気後退期{けいきこうたいき}を過{す}ぎれば、この国{くに}の経済{けいざい}は最悪{さいあく}の状態{じょうたい}を脱{だっ}するかもしれません。」

「～～**を**過ぎる」, in this context, means "***to get through***".

「過ぎれば」 is indeed in the conditional form.

> "If (we) get through the two-year recession, this country's economy might be out of the worst situation."

Comment: 「過ぎる」って、明鏡には「自動詞」しか載ってない・・・　「角を曲がる」「道を歩く」「空を飛ぶ」「得意先を回る」みたいなやつ？

Comment: ホンマでっか？う～ん、その「を + 自動詞」かどうか分からんさかいに一旦編集するわ。